# Unable to return yielded item to Scrapydo run_spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am calling the Scrapy spider using scrapydo run_spider method but Spider parse method is unable to return the yielded items

Parse method. It basically calls the Spider's parse method dynamically which uploads the file to S3 and then yielded the item

```
    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        spider = None
        try:
            product_url = response.meta.get('url') or response.request.url
            spider = self._get_spider(merchant_id=response.request.meta.get('merchant_id'))
            if spider:
                generators = spider.parse(response)
                for generator in generators:
                    yield generator
            else:
                logger.info('Cannot found any spider for url %s', product_url)
        except Exception as err:
            if spider:
                Log.save_exception(module=self.TAG_NAME, error=err, merchant_id=spider.merchant_id)
            else:
                Log.save_exception(module=self.TAG_NAME, error=err)
```

Scrapydo Code

````
    def test_file_manager(self, test_input: dict):
        """
        Test file manager. It runs the spider and check the output

        :param test_input: test input
        """
        cache_database = CacheDatabaseToRedis()
        cache_database.sync()

        redis_data = test_input["redis_data"]
        redis_data["merchant_id"] = self.merchant_id

        RedisService().push_objects_into_queue(
            queue_name=REDIS_ITEM_DOC_URLS_KEY, objects=[json.dumps(redis_data)]
        )

        actual_outputs = self.run_spider(
            spider_cls=self.master_spider_cls,
            capture_items=True
        )

        if len(actual_outputs) == 0:
            self.assert_actual_value_not_available()
        else:
            for actual_output in actual_outputs:
                super().test_parse(test_input=test_input, actual_output=actual_output)
    ```
````